# Decoding python data

Tags: python, string, hex, byte, decode

Sorry for what might be a quite simple question. I know a few languages, but I'm new regarding python.
I'm collecting via an IOT device the following data and here are all the info I can get :

```
print('This is my data : %s' % (data)) => "This is my data : b'\x95\xfe683475065015121'"
print(type(data)) => "<class 'str'>"
```

The thing is, I'd like to get numeric values extracted from data such as :

- Discard the \x95\xfe at the begining
- a = 68.3 (3 first digits / 10)
- b = 475 or 475.0 (3 next digits)
- c = 065 or 65.0 (3 next digits)...
- ... (I'll get the rest from here I think.)

Thanks a lot for your help and have a great day.

PS : I already tried float.fromhex(data[y:Z]) - or data.decode("hex"), but no luck... bytes.fromhex(data[y:z]) got me a strange result as well...

Comment: How do you get `data`?  It looks like it is a stringified `bytes` instance, which means it been cast to `str` at some earlier point in your code.

Comment: I recieved it via a python plugin to wich I do not have access...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
t = b'\x95\xfe683475065015121'
t = t[2:]  # disregard \x95\xfe
print(t)

a = int(t[:3]) / 10
b = int(t[3:6])
c = int(t[6:9])
print(a, b, c)  # >>> 68.3 475 65
```